# Выделяется ли запятыми "чур"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Только чур(,) я первый" — "чур" как-то нужно выделять запятыми или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чур - это междометие. Ожегов называет одно из значений этого слова - "возглас, которым требуют соблюдать какое-либо условие: Чур я первый. Только чур я остаюсь.Чур это секрет". Так что запятая в Вашем предложении не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

То, что «чур» — междометие, еще не значит, что ему не положены запятые.
«Чур» обособляется в большинстве заслуживающих доверия текстов.
«Чур меня» — практически всегда.

> Междометия — это особая часть речи, которая служит для выражения различных чувств и волевых побуждений. К этой части речи относятся слова АЙ!, АХ!, УВЫ!, БАТЮШКИ! и другие. 
>   ***Междометия, как и обращения, не являются членами предложения, а на письме отделяются запятой или восклицательным знаком.***
>
> (Грамота, курсив мой — B-s).

Насколько могу судить, одиночный «чур» не обособляется главным образом, если используется в значении сказуемого (главного члена) или наречия. И еще в начале предложения, где по грамматической функции оно очень напоминает частицу.

В вашем примере, полагаю, возможна двоякая пунктуация. *Чур* может обособляться, но не обязательно.